# Shifting array elements by n positions

Tags: c++, c, arrays, gcc, g++

I have basic knowledge in C, C++ and im trying to insert n elements at k positions in an array and shift the k+1 element in the array.
I have used two for loops  for this

```
void insert(int n,int k)
{
  int temp=arrayA[k][4];

  for(int u=k+1;u<=rowA;u++)
  {
    arrayA[k+n][4]=arrayA[k+1][4];
    arrayA[k+n][3]=Bigradius;
    arrayA[k+n][2]=arrayA[k+1][2];
    arrayA[k+n][1]=arrayA[k+1][1];
    arrayA[k+n][0]=arrayA[k+1][0];
  }

  for(int pos=k;pos<=k+n-1;pos++,)
  {   
    arrayA[pos][4]=temp;
    arrayA[pos][3]=B
    arrayA[pos][2]=s1;
    arrayA[pos][1]=s2;
    arrayA[pos][0]=s3;  
  }  
}
```

where n is no of new elements,k is the position where new elements are inserted,s1,s2,s3..are some values

if initial file is
   0.74172455 0.03613250 0.82822931 0.03121938 0
   0.45620244 0.33476580 0.92169053 0.03121938 1
   0.13701758 0.74540644 0.56569663 0.03121938 2
   0.94162524 0.13094005 0.62107182 0.03121938 3

but in output if im inserting 3 elements in position 0,then elements at position 1,2 are missing

```
-0.0104065  0.0312194 0.0728452 0.0104065      0 
 0.0104065 -0.0312194 0.0520323 0.0104065      0 
 0.0104065 -0.0312194 0.0520323 0.0312194      0 
 0.941625   0.13094   0.621072  0.0312194      3
```

Comment: C or C++ ? use `std::vector` if it is C++

Comment: Before you even begin solving for algorithmic functionality. Maybe it's best to read some books on c++ basics; there are many syntax errors in the code

Comment: Too many to reasonably answers in one question, to not make the answer and question off topic . If possible break the snippet down and report :)

Comment: I dont want to be too pedantic, but this code wont compile (there is at least one missing `;`). Please post real code that produces the error

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak what "many" syntax errors do you mean? I can spot one, but thats enough to know that this code does not produce the output OP claims

Comment: Plus your last comment, there is "rowA" which I can't see an initialization for.

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak which means the OP doesnt show a [mcve] but thats probably not a syntax error. It might be a global variable

Comment: Agreed, but as its supposed to safely bound arrayA, for the outer loop seems a little strange why it is neither k-1, not 3. But yeah, fair nuf

Answer (score 0):

To insert `n` elements at index `k` of an array, try this **logic**:

Initialize an **original** array having the elements. Now, take the values of `n`, `k` in the variables and the **n** elements to insert in another array (let's say **to_add[]**) from the user. Now, initialize a **second** array of length = **length of main array** + **n**.
**(1)** Having all the required values and arrays initialized, run a loop from index = `0` to index = `k-1` of the main array and copy those elements to the the second array.
**(2)** Now, run a second loop from index = `k` to index = `k  + n - 1` for the second array and copy all the elements for the index = `index - k` of the to_add array into the second array.
**(3)** Lastly, run a third loop from index = `k + n` to index = `(length of second array) - 1` of the second array and copy all the elements for index = `index - n` of the main array into the second array.

Here's the C++ code for the above logic.

```
int k,n;
int main_array[x] = { /* elements of the original array */ };
/* display the main array */
cout << "Enter index position at which to enter elements \n" ;
cin >> k;
cout << "\n How many elements do you want to enter? \n" ;
cin >> n;
int to_add[n];
int final_array[x+n];
/* accept elements to be added into the to_add array */

//first loop
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
    final_array[i] = main_array[i];
}

//second loop
for(int i = k; i < k+n; i++){
    final_array[i] = to_add[i-k];
}

//last loop
for(int i = k+n; i < x+n; i++){
    final_array[i] = main_array[i-n];
}

/* display the final_array */
```

I hope you understand it and it solves your problem.